# Activating lockscreen using systemd doesn't work

Tags: linux, hibernate, thinkpad, systemd, i3

I'm trying to activate the `betterlockscreen` every time I close my laptop using this systemd service file:

```
[Unit]
Description = Lock screen when going to sleep/suspend
Before=sleep.target
Before=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/betterlockscreen --lock
TimeoutSec=infinity
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1   

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

When I run `systemctl status betterlockscreen@$USER` I see

```
○ betterlockscreen@tom.service - Lock screen when going to sleep/suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/betterlockscreen@.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-09-21 20:49:58 CEST; 3h 28min ago
   Main PID: 168557 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 763ms

Sep 21 20:33:18 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 systemd[1]: Starting Lock screen when going to sleep/suspend...
Sep 21 20:33:18 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 betterlockscreen[168557]: [B] Betterlockscreen
Sep 21 20:33:18 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 betterlockscreen[168557]: [*] Running prelock...
Sep 21 20:33:18 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 betterlockscreen[168557]: [*] Locking screen... (FAILSAFE MODE)
Sep 21 20:33:18 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 betterlockscreen[168557]: [*] Running postlock...
Sep 21 20:49:58 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 systemd[1]: betterlockscreen@tom.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 21 20:49:58 tom-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-Gen-9 systemd[1]: Started Lock screen when going to sleep/suspend.
```

Executing `/usr/local/bin/betterlockscreen --lock` in the command line locks the screen as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works now, although I'm not quite sure why.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I tried multiple ways to fix it but none seem to work.
After taking a look at this [https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=279840\](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=279840%5C)
I switched my display manager from [sddm](https://github.com/sddm/sddm) to [ly](https://github.com/fairyglade/ly#readme) and now it works perfectly.

Here is the `betterlockscreen@$USER` config i use:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock screen when going to sleep/suspend
Before=sleep.target
Before=suspend.target

[Service]
User=%I
Type=simple
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/betterlockscreen --lock
TimeoutSec=infinity
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 1

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend.target
```